# How to filter by rating with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hotel list pages and I want to filtering my hotels by rating like [trivago filtering](https://www.trivago.com/?cpt=3422803&iRoomType=7&iPathId=34228&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2017-05-14&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2017-05-15&iGeoDistanceItem=0&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false) (like the picture below)

[image]

and I'm only showing matched result it's okey so far but I guess something is missing I mean I can show more than one filter for example bad and excellent or from normal to very good if you check out my code you are gonna understand what I mean.I try to same trivago filtering and only this section I couldn't do

so here you are what I tried until now

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var dataRate = $(this).attr("data-rate");

    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).nextAll().css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).prevAll().css("opacity", "0.5");
    $("#content .filter-list").hide();

    $('#content .filter-list[data-show-list="' + dataRate + '"]').show();

  });
})
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#filter {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<main id="wrap">

  <div id="filter">
    <button data-rate="bad" style="background:#cc0033;color:#fff" name="rating">bad</button>
    <button data-rate="normal" style="background:orange;color:#fff" name="rating">normal</button>
    <button data-rate="good" style="background:#99cc00;color:#fff" name="rating">good</button>
    <button data-rate="verygood" style="background:green;color:#fff" name="rating">very good</button>
    <button data-rate="excellent" style="background:darkgreen;color:#fff" name="rating">excellent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- filter-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="good">
      I'm a very good
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      this is the bad list
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="verygood">
      I'm a very good to
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="excellent">
      Excellent!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="normal">
      Iııh normal!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="good">
      Good - enough thanks
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      Bad - don't ever..
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="excellent">
      Excellent again
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      isn't bad ? I think yes bad..
    </div>
  </div>


</main>
```

Comment: Set a value to each rating for example `Very very bad = 0` and `Excellent = 10` and use this number to filter

Comment: thanks but how wil I apply that with my code ? I'm a new on jquery how will I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using numeric values for the different rating types.
This is just one way to do it, sure you'll get the idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $list = $("#content").find(".filter-list");
  var $btn = $("button");

  $btn.on("click", function() {
  
    var dataRate = $(this).attr("data-rate");
    
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).nextAll().css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).prevAll().css("opacity", "0.5");
    
    $list.show();
    
    $list
      .filter(function(idx, item) {
        return item.dataset.showList < dataRate;
      })
      .each(function(idx, item) {
        $(item).hide();
      })

  });
})
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#filter {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<main id="wrap">

  <div id="filter">
    <button data-rate="1" style="background:#cc0033;color:#fff" name="rating">bad</button>
    <button data-rate="2" style="background:orange;color:#fff" name="rating">normal</button>
    <button data-rate="3" style="background:#99cc00;color:#fff" name="rating">good</button>
    <button data-rate="4" style="background:green;color:#fff" name="rating">very good</button>
    <button data-rate="5" style="background:darkgreen;color:#fff" name="rating">excellent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- filter-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="3">
      I'm a very good
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="1">
      this is the bad list
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="4">
      I'm a very good to
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="5">
      Excellent!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="2">
      Iııh normal!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="3">
      Good - enough thanks
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="1">
      Bad - don't ever..
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="5">
      Excellent again
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="1">
      isn't bad ? I think yes bad..
    </div>
  </div>


</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a selected class on each button when clicked.

Loop through all the selected buttons to create array of the filter values.

Then use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on the items and compare each data attribute to the filter array to see if it should be included or not

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $btns = $('#filter button'),
    $items = $("#content .filter-list");
    
  $btns.on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    // create filter values array from all selected buttons
    var filterArray = $btns.filter('.selected').map(function() {
      return $(this).data('rate')
    }).get();
  
    if (filterArray.length) {
      // hide all items, then filter ones that match above array to show
      $items.hide().filter(function() {
        var rating = $(this).data('show-list');
        // only include if rating is in array
        return $.inArray(rating, filterArray) > -1;
      }).show();

    } else {
      $items.show()
    }

  });
})
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

button.selected {
  opacity: 1
}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#filter {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<main id="wrap">

  <div id="filter">
    <button data-rate="bad" style="background:#cc0033;color:#fff" name="rating">bad</button>
    <button data-rate="normal" style="background:orange;color:#fff" name="rating">normal</button>
    <button data-rate="good" style="background:#99cc00;color:#fff" name="rating">good</button>
    <button data-rate="verygood" style="background:green;color:#fff" name="rating">very good</button>
    <button data-rate="excellent" style="background:darkgreen;color:#fff" name="rating">excellent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- filter-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="good">
      I'm a very good
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      this is the bad list
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="verygood">
      I'm a very good to
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="excellent">
      Excellent!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="normal">
      Iııh normal!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="good">
      Good - enough thanks
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      Bad - don't ever..
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="excellent">
      Excellent again
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list" data-show-list="bad">
      isn't bad ? I think yes bad..
    </div>
  </div>


</main>
```

Comment: oow this is the first time I see  `return $.inArray(rating, filterArray) > -1` I'm asking to understand and another question all button musn't be opacity in default and how to show all filter list when clicked from bad to excellent ? this example so good and I learn something about filter and I'll learn array thanks to you

Comment: You will need to work out some css. I only made them low opacity to start and used selected class to make them full opacity for this demo to easily see what was selected and what wasn't